# Upload .WMV and .FLV using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, upload

I would like to upload .wmv and .flv files using Uploadify and PHP. However, I can't seem to get it right.

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'swf'         : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'    : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'uploadLimit' : 1,
        'folder'    : 'uploads',
        'method'   : 'post',
        'auto'      : true,
        'multi'     : true,
        'fileExt'   : '*.jpg; *.gif; *.png; *.jpeg; *.wmv; *.flv',
         'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        alert('The file was saved to: ' + file);
             } 
    });
});
```

Uplodify.php

```
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','wmv'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What error is shown? What happens when you test it? Why haven't you accepted an answer for any of your questions?

Comment: This other question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072889/uploadify-alternative-need-to-upload-large-1gb-files

Comment: error is not show. just simply complete the process. but the files are not moves on destination folder. if i upload the image files then it moves.  @Alfabravo

Comment: Have you considered asking for support on the [Uploadify Forums](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/)? Might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to increase the maximum upload limit have a read of http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/increase-maximum-php-upload-size/

Comment: Ok try setting up a test page with a normal html upload form and see if that works this should help you debug your problem.

Comment: Are you seeing an error now though. If not turn on all PHP errors and see if you then see something.